# How can I translate a TupleExpr or a ParsedTupleQuery into the Query String?

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, rdf4j

I want to parse a query using rdf4j's SPARQLParser, modify the underlying query tree (=TupleExpr) and translate it back into a query string. Is there a way to do that with rdf4j?

I tried the following but it didn't work

```
 SPARQLParser parser = new SPARQLParser();
 ParsedQuery originalQuery =  parser.parseQuery(query, null);
    if (originalQuery instanceof ParsedTupleQuery) {
        TupleExpr queryTree = originalQuery.getTupleExpr();
        queryTree.visit(myQueryModelVisitor());
        originalQuery.setTupleExpr(queryTree);
        System.out.println(queryTree);
        ParsedQuery tsQuery = new ParsedTupleQuery(queryTree);
        System.out.println(tsQuery.getSourceString());

    }
```

the printed output is null.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `org.eclipse.rdf4j.queryrender.sparql.experimental.SparqlQueryRenderer` which is specifically designed to transform a TupleExpr back into a SPARQL query string.

Roughly, like this:

```java
SPARQLParser parser = new SPARQLParser();
 ParsedQuery originalQuery =  parser.parseQuery(query, null);
    if (originalQuery instanceof ParsedTupleQuery) {
        TupleExpr queryTree = originalQuery.getTupleExpr();
        queryTree.visit(myQueryModelVisitor());
        originalQuery.setTupleExpr(queryTree);
        System.out.println(queryTree);
        ParsedQuery tsQuery = new ParsedTupleQuery(queryTree);
        String transformedQuery = new SparqlQueryRenderer().render(tsQuery);
}
```

Note that this component is still experimental, and does not have guaranteed complete coverage of all SPARQL 1.1 features.

As an aside, the reason `getSourceString()` does not work here is that method is designed to return the input source string from which the parsed query was generated. Since in your case you've just created a new `ParsedQuery` object from scratch, there *is* no source string.